# Adding a UniqueConstraint to a ManyToMany field

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, unique-constraint

I want to add a constraint to my database so that an application can only ever be associated with one vacancy. I don't want to be able to go in from the shell or django admin page, go into a vacancy and select an application that is already associated with a vacancy. I would like some kind of validation error to be raised. But I am a little unsure how I should go about this?

**models.py**

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('ADMINISTRATION', 'Administration'),
        ('CONSULTING', 'Consulting'),
        ('ENGINEERING', 'Engineering'),
        ('FINANCE', 'Finance'),
        ('RETAIL', 'Retail'),
        ('SALES', 'Sales'),
    ]
    employer = models.ForeignKey('Employer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=35, default=None)
    main_duties = models.TextField(default=None, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(650),
        MaxLengthValidator(2000)
    ])
    person_spec = models.TextField(default=None, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(650),
        MaxLengthValidator(2000)
    ])
    salary = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, validators=[
        MinValueValidator(20000), 
        MaxValueValidator(99000)
    ])
    city = models.CharField(choices=CITY_CHOICES, max_length=11, default=None)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=15, default=None)
    max_applications = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(default=None)
    applications = models.ManyToManyField('Application', blank=True, related_name='submissions')
    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'vacancies'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['id', 'applications'], name="unique_application")
        ]


class Application(models.Model):
    STAGES = [
        ('pre-selection', 'PRE-SELECTION'),
        ('shortlisted', 'SHORTLISTED'),
        ('rejected pre-interview', 'REJECTED PRE-INTERVIEW'),
        ('rejected post-interview', 'REJECTED POST-INTERVIEW'),
        ('successful', 'SUCCESSFUL')
    ]
    candidate = models.ForeignKey('Candidate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey('Vacancy', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cv = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default=None, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(0),
        MaxLengthValidator(2000)
    ])
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    stage = models.CharField(choices=STAGES, max_length=25, default='pre-selection')
```

As you can see I have added a constraint to the Vacancy model:

```
constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['id', 'applications'], name="unique_application")
        ]
```

But when I do `makemigrations` and then `migrate`, I get this error:

```
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: NewVacancy has no field named 'applications'
```

and it is not clear to me what this means.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like one to many relation. You can move to a `ForeignKey` on `Application` with the `related_name=applications` instead of `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('ADMINISTRATION', 'Administration'),
        ('CONSULTING', 'Consulting'),
        ('ENGINEERING', 'Engineering'),
        ('FINANCE', 'Finance'),
        ('RETAIL', 'Retail'),
        ('SALES', 'Sales'),
    ]
    employer = models.ForeignKey('Employer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=35, default=None)
    main_duties = models.TextField(default=None, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(650),
        MaxLengthValidator(2000)
    ])
    person_spec = models.TextField(default=None, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(650),
        MaxLengthValidator(2000)
    ])
    salary = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=None, validators=[
        MinValueValidator(20000),
        MaxValueValidator(99000)
    ])
    city = models.CharField(choices=CITY_CHOICES, max_length=11, default=None)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=15, default=None)
    max_applications = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(default=None)


class Application(models.Model):
    STAGES = [
        ('pre-selection', 'PRE-SELECTION'),
        ('shortlisted', 'SHORTLISTED'),
        ('rejected pre-interview', 'REJECTED PRE-INTERVIEW'),
        ('rejected post-interview', 'REJECTED POST-INTERVIEW'),
        ('successful', 'SUCCESSFUL')
    ]
    candidate = models.ForeignKey('Candidate', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey('Vacancy', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cv = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None)
    cover_letter = models.TextField(default=None, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(0),
        MaxLengthValidator(2000)
    ])
    submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    stage = models.CharField(choices=STAGES, max_length=25, default='pre-selection')
    vacancy = models.ForeignKey(Vacancy, related_name='applications', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Comment: But what if I need that to remain a `ManyToManyField`. Is there a way to ensure that each `application` on my `Vacancy` table is linked to only one... say, `city` (charfield) ?